# Custom field in external Javascript

Tags: custom-field, javascript

How do I use a custom filed value in an external javascript?
I'd like to use a custom field already stored for a post that is an url in an external javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/scripts.js'></script>
```

in order to open a new window

```
onclick="window.open('MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE');"
```

I tried to add

```
global $post; $cf = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true );
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be able to do with Ajax. You have the control of the 'external JavaScript' ?

Comment: yes I have control of the javascript... I've created it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using custom field values in a widget that used JavaScript. I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.bluewordpressthemes.com/wordpress-widgets-php-javascript-variable/) explaining it. Try this code:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$cf = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true);     
?>

<button onclick="window.open(<?php echo json_encode($cf); ?>);">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I have to insert your code in the js file? In my js I'd like to insert the function that I call in the `<a href="openWindows()"...` so I need to call the custom field directly from the js